# Does Groovy security flaw affect Grails apps?

Tags: security, grails, serialization, groovy

A security flaw in Groovy was detected in versions 1.7 to 2.4.3:

http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-3253

> The MethodClosure class in runtime/MethodClosure.java in Apache Groovy 1.7.0 through 2.4.3 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause a denial of service via a crafted serialized object.

Does this affect "typical" Grails projects that retrieve data from user input (web forms), the DB, web services, etc. and assume this is all text, not serialized objects? In other words, is there any of this happening implicitly that we should be aware of?

Otherwise, what should we look for to ensure this bug isn't affecting us?

Comment: Did you even look into the details of the issue? http://groovy-lang.org/security.html Note the section that says "When an application has Groovy on the classpath and that it uses standard Java serialization mechanim to communicate between servers, or to store local data, it is possible ..." So, unless your application does then you aren't going to be worried about this.

Comment: Yes, I read that, it's linked to in the issue I posted. But Grails is large and complex and depends on a lot of other frameworks like Spring, Hibernate, and their dependencies. As I wrote, my concern was over "implict" deserialization outside our own application code. I don't think that's unreasonable to ask the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grame has an issue for exactly this, but noone has been able to show any way to exploit it in a Grails app yet: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9113

In short: "the plan is 2.5.1 and 3.0.4 will have Groovy 2.4.4"